# Put last 4 objects of an ascending array into UITableView

Tags: objective-c, arrays, uitableview

My array (trips) grows depending on how many entries a user has made.  Currently the array is in ascending order from the database.

I need to have it start at the last object and populate my tableview with the last 4 'trips' objects from the array.

My tableview only shows 4 rows, I want those rows to be the last 4 from the array.

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
if ([trips count] < 4){
    return [trips count]
    } else {
    return 4;
    }
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyReuseIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle  reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    }

    UserMiles *cellInfo = [self milesAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ to %@", cellInfo.beg_school, cellInfo.end_school];


    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    dateFormat.dateFormat = @"MM/dd/yyyy";
    NSString *date = [dateFormat stringFromDate:cellInfo.driven_date];

    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", date];

    return cell;
}

-(UserMiles *) milesAtIndex: (NSInteger) index
{
    return [trips objectAtIndex:index];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `NSSortDescriptor` to get the array into the order you want.  The quickest fix would be to just take your `milesAtIndex:` and change it to:

```
-(UserMiles *) milesAtIndex: (NSInteger) index
{
    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"propertyHere" ascending:NO];
    return [[trips sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]] objectAtIndex:index];
}
```

Note that `@"propertyHere"` can be any property of your `UserMiles` object that you want to sort by.  So if you are using a date for example, you might have a `myUserMiles.tripDate` property, so you'd replace `@"propertyHere"` with `@"tripDate"`.

Comment: I used your method (as well as my answer) and both work appropriately.  I'm going to accept yours as the answer though, because I appreciate you taking the time to look at it :)

Comment: @Hanny: Why thank you.  `reverseObjectEnumerator` works nicely for just simply flipping whatever you already have, which is all you needed in this case, but I like `NSSortDescriptor` better because it's a lot more flexible - you can sort by whatever property you want, and it doesn't depend at all on what the order was before you call it.

Comment: Most definitely!  I can see where this would be really useful and I'm glad this is such a clean, simple example.  I've already used it again elsewhere in my code :)  Thanks again, cheers!  On a site note, I had another problem setting a pickerview (here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22183025/odd-error-when-setting-uipickerview-selection-with-appropriate-date-selectrow-c) if you've got any extra insight there too ;)  Cheers mate!

Answer (score 0):

I utilized the reverseObjectEnumerator class (which I had no idea existed!) to get it done.

It now works great!

```
trips = [[trips reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];
```